# Error in Passing PHP value to another page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I have an HTML which displays data from a database table. There'a checkbox field, which stores id of the user. And when I click on a row, that ID has to be passed to another page using a JavaScript function. But I have encountered a few errors. I don't know where I went wrong.

This is my Javascript function. It is used to make the table rows clickable. SO when I click on a row, the corresponding ID is passed to editgroup.php page.

```
<script>
    $('table.table tbody tr').click(function(event)
    {
       if(event.target.type === 'checkbox')
       {
            event.preventdefault()
       }
       else
       {
        window.location='edituser.php?val=<?php echo $id; ?>';
       }
    }); 
</script>
```

Below given is my table:

```
<table id="edituser" class="clickable"
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>UserID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++)
            {
             $id= $val_array[$i]['id'];                                  
            $userName= $val_array[$i]['userName'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"></td>
            <td><?php echo $id;  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $userName;  ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't write `javascript` mixed up with `php`

Comment: Is there a solution??? @Ranjith

Comment: @TheJoker I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make some change

First in your tr add id like this

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++)
{
 $id= $val_array[$i]['id'];  //data from database                                
$userName= $val_array[$i]['userName']; //data from database  
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $id;?>"> <!-- add id here -->
<td ><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $id;  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $userName;  ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

now your JS

```
<script>
            $('table.clickable tbody tr').click(function(event){
                if(event.target.type === 'checkbox'){
                    event.preventdefault()
                }else{
                    var val = $(this).attr('id');
                    window.location='edituser.php?val='+val;
                }
            }); </script>
```

Comment: returns undefined. @Satish Sharma

Comment: @TheJoker wrong class is applied in the jquery i had changed it see the updated jquery function and try now.  i had added class `clickable` in jquery

Comment: returns undefined again. @Satish Sharma

Comment: make some more changes in jquery function try now

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript will be

```
      $('table.table tbody tr').click(function(event){
            if(event.target.type === 'checkbox'){
                event.preventdefault()
            }else{
                var value = (this).find("input[type='checkbox']").val();   /* Get value from clicked tr Checkbox */
                window.location.replace('edituser.php?val='+value); /* Pass the value */
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new function with dynamic `id` for your `table row`

```
<tr onclick="edit_user(<?php echo $id;?>)" >
      ....
</tr>
```

Then you can find your `row` of where you have to `click`

```
<script>
    function edit_user(user_id) {
       if(user_id != '') {
           window.location='edituser.php?val='+user_id;
       }
    }
</script>
```

**Or else**

This is more even simple your code.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>" onclick="document.location.href='edituser.php?val=<?php echo $id; ?>'">
```